# Is it a good programming to pass Connection Object to a method?

Tags: jdbc

I am doing a Insert Operation , i have a condition if **company is 0** , then i need to perform an additional insert in another table ??

This is my code

```
public  static  String insertIntoDepotTable(DepotJSONBean depotbean) throws SQLException
    {
        Connection dbConnection = null;
        PreparedStatement depotjsoninsertPst = null ;
        try
        {
            dbConnection = DBConnectionOrientDepot.getDBConnection();
            dbConnection.setAutoCommit(false);


            String companyId = depotbean.getCompanyId();

            if(companyId.equals("0"))
            {
                saveInCompany(depotbean , dbConnection);
            }


            String Insertsql = "INSERT INTO tbl_depot values (depotID,depoBelongsToID,stateID,districtID,talukMandalID,depotName,companyID,contactName,phone1,phone2,address,latitude,longititude,accuracy,town,noOfPeopleOperating,depotSize,storageCapacity,cAndFNames,depotPic1,depotPic2,comments,active,createdOn,modifiedOn) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            depotjsoninsertPst = dbConnection.prepareStatement(Insertsql);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

            }
    } // end of method

public String saveInCompany(DepotJSONBean djsonbean , Connection conn)
{

}
```

Comment: I don't see why not.

Comment: ok thank you , i guess i must not close the connection under the method saveInCompany method ?? am i correct ?

Comment: No, I would think the connection would be closed within the scope of the code that created it.